# Can i forward print jobs from one printer to another in windows?

Tags: windows, printer

I want to forward all the jobs from one printer to another on Windows XP, Vist, 7,8 - is this possible? The scenario would be any print job printed on one would also be printed on the other in a chained fashion.

EDIT: The printers are all local

Comment: What do you want to do ? What is your setup ? Be more explicit

Comment: Are these printers shared via a print server? Or printing direct? IP/USB/LPT/etc?

Comment: So printing to Printer A would send the jobs to B, C and D?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for print mirroring, not forwarding.

To the best of my knowledge, this kind of setup is not possible with the native Windows print spooler. You'll have to get fancy to accomplish this.

Fancy, in this case, would be a custom print-provider. There are third party utilities (paid, I know of no free ones) that do this, as that kind of setup is occasionally found in high print situations like Higher Education computer labs.

How it works is that when you create a new print queue, you create it through a custom print port. This is a software shim that can do things like mirror print jobs between other queues on the system or do more intelligent print-pooling than the native Windows system.

Comment: I actually know of, and have used very successfully, a free one. http://www.andtechnologies.com/index.php?q=free-software/multiprinter-port

Comment: @mfinni PCounter, of course. We used their commercial software for our labs. Good stuff.

Comment: @mfinni thanks for that. I downloaded it but get an error when I try to run it. The 'about' of the program says it supports versions up to 2000 - have you had any success on Vista, 7 or 8?

Comment: The error was 'The environment specified is invalid' - looks like it's x64 related

Comment: @sysadmin1138 I'd also be interested to see any commercial products you might recommend.

Comment: @Richard I'm not familiar with the market anymore, so I really can't.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I haven't used that since Win2k, and it filled the need quite nicely at the time. Shame it hasn't kept up. If you had a 32-bit print server, you could install it on there and simply share it, perhaps. That's not a long-term solution of course.